# R: Missing one bar in a bar-graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a bar graph showing the mean and standard deviation of soil carbon concentration among different climate types. X represents climate types (11 types), and y represents carbon.

The data is imported from a CSV. file. First, I process the data.

```
library(plyr)
data_summary <- function(varname,groupnames){
  require(plyr)
  summary_func <- function(x,col){
    c(mean = mean(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE)),
    sd = sd(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))
 }
 data_sum <- ddply(data, groupnames, .fun=summary_func,
                   varname)
 data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("mean"=varname))
return(data_sum)

df3 <- data_summary(SOC, varname="Concentration",
                         groupnames="Climate")
```

Then I make the variable ''Climate" as factor and reorder it.

```
df3$Climate <- as.factor(df3$Climate)

df3$Climate <- factor(df3$Climate, 
                      levels = c("Tropical rainforest", "Tropical savanna", "Tropical monsoon", 
                                 "Subtropical monsoon", "Temperate oceanic", "Temperate monsoon", 
                                 "Temperate continental", "Mediterranean", "Mountain plateau", 
                                 "Desert", "Arctic"))
```

Then I start to make a bar graph

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df3, aes(x=Climate, y=Concentration)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", fill="white", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= Concentration, ymax= Concentration +sd), 
                width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))

print(p)
p + coord_flip() + ylab("SOC Concentration")
```

The following graph is the result I had. As you can see, there is one bar missing: the Mediterranean bar. I got a message from R:

> Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_bar)

[image]

I am sure that the problem is not related to the function like

> scale_y_continuous or ylim=c(number,number)

I also try some functions like

> p + scale_x_discrete or xlim=c(Tropical rainforest:Arctic)

However, I still can't make it. Hope you can tell me what I can adjust to get the missing bar back. I am a new beginner, the code is referred from other people who want to make a similar bar graph. If I can use another way to make it, please also let me know.

Comment: check if this is a typo ```factor(df3$Climate, levels = c("Tropical rainforest", "Tropical savanna", "Tropical monsoon", "Subtropical monsoon", "Temperate oceanic", "Temperate monsoon", "Temperate continental, "Mediterranean", Mountain plateau", "Desert", "Arctic"))```

Comment: it should be ```..."Temperate continental", "Mediterranean"...``` there is a missing quote

Comment: Yes, there is a missing quote, but that is just I was careless when typing in the post. In the R system, I did have those quotes, but I can't make it. Thank you. (btw, no typo, thank you)

Comment: Hmm the error comes from setting the factors. if you do ```table(is.na(df3$Climate))``` you will see there are NAs. I suspect the ```"Mediterranean"``` level is typed wrongly